# Query paypal stock management to show on my website for customers

Tags: paypal, counter, inventory, stock

Is it possible to have an active automatic stock counter on my website (for each item drop down box), that queries from my paypal button's stock inventory?

So if someone buys, the stock counter for that particular item goes down automatically, like it does on paypal's end. But I want it to be shown on my website for my customers to see how much stock is actually left. Is this possible with paypal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check the [BMGetButtonDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMGetButtonDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) API and see if it'll provide it for you.